# Is Armor Class a difficulty class (DC)?

Tags: conditions, pathfinder-2e, armor-class, difficulty-class

[Frightened](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=19) talks only about DCs:

> [...] You take a status penalty equal to this value to all your checks and **DCs** [...]

Compare it to [Clumsy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=3):

> [...] You take a status penalty equal to the condition value to Dexterity-based checks and **DCs, including AC**, Reflex saves, ranged attack rolls, and skill checks [...]

The wording of Clumsy seems to imply that AC is just one of the DCs, but is not clear. I really hope it is, otherwise Frightened is not nearly as good as I thought.

Comment: Strange, I thought we'd already asked this here but don't see it.

Comment: I felt really stupid when I saw the answer, but now, based on the number of upvotes, I guess it was not that clear for other people either.

Comment: It was a huge debate for a while. I'm thinking they snuck some rewording on on an errata because I don't actually *remember* it being that clear

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Armor Class is also a Difficulty Class

Armor Class is referenced in multiple locations as a DC. Most notably, in the [rules in Equipment](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=199) about AC:

> Your Armor Class (AC) measures how well you can defend against attacks. When a creature attacks you, **your Armor Class is the DC for that attack roll.**

And also Playing the Game [Key Terms](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=19)

> All creatures in the game have an Armor Class. This score represents how hard it is to hit and damage a creature. It serves as the Difficulty Class for hitting a creature with an attack.

Because this is a little ambiguous (being "the DC for that ... roll" vs "you have a DC that is your AC"), you can also reference the rules on [attacks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=324):

> Attack rolls are compared to a special **difficulty class called an Armor Class (AC)**, which measures how hard it is for your foes to hit you...

Comment: Found another one (CRB p12): _"Armor class (AC) All creatures in the game have an Armor Class. This score represents how hard it is to hit and damage a creature. __It
serves as the Difficulty Class for hitting a creature with an attack__."_